# How to fetch the URL without path params in HttpServletRequest in java

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey

I have a rate limiter which will limit the API Calls made to the REST endpoint based on the endpoint to which the call is made.
So if there are the following 2 endpoints:
GET:/module/v1/fetchSomeData/{_id}
DELETE:/module/v1/subModule/deleteDataFor/{parent_id}/{child_id}

Now, when I do:
httpServletRequest.getRequestURI: I get the entire path /module/v1/fetchSomeData/123
I tried the other functions in httpServletRequest as well, but none of them separate out the "123" from rest of the URL so that I can rate limit that particular endpoint.
Worst case: I'd have gone for regex, but just like the DELETE endpoint I've mentioned, there is no one-fits-all regex I could use - they're varying in the endpoint or the parameter length.

Comment: HttpServletRequest is a low-level object that provides you access to a raw HTTP request.  It has no knowledge of JAX-RS.  Therefore, it has no knowledge of URI templates or path parameters.  I’m not clear on why you need to distinguish the template parts.  Isn’t `path.startsWith("/module/va/fetchSomeData/")` sufficient to match the request?